# Detecting input

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a completely automated program that only stops if I happen to be using the computer when it begins to run. To do so when the program begins it waits for 10 seconds to see if the computer is idle, then if it is, the program continues running. However, I am having issues breaking it if I do something.The issue is that I'm trying to break the loop if the last input was 0 seconds ago, meaning I am on the computer; however, when I start the timer it's at 0, so it breaks the loop.

I tried putting the time.sleep inbetween the if statement and the get last input, but it still starts at zero.

```
def wait():
        while 1:
            GetLastInputInfo = int(get_idle_duration())
            time.sleep(1)
            if GetLastInputInfo == 0:
                break
            if get_idle_duration() > 10:
                warthunder()
                killProcess()
                break
        print('Done')
```

I expect for the program to wait 10 seconds and if my mouse is moved or if a key is pressed for the program to break.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. Here's the updated code:

```
def wait():
        while 1:
            time.sleep(1)
            if get_idle_duration() == 0.0:
                break
            if get_idle_duration() > 10:
                warthunder()
                killProcess()
                break
        print('Done')
```

I got ride of the GetLastInput variable, and changed the first if statement to a float